# Auto Tweeting from Twitter Bot

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, twitter4j

Today I made a Twitter Bot of a cow that tweets different variations of the word "Moo." (Hilarious, I know). In my code I have it so it tweets every hour. I am wondering if anyone knows a way to run my code without having to have Eclipse open all day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have written your program properly all you have to do is to build the project and run the Jar-file.

[Everything you need to know about Jar-files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html)